# Why doesn't ruby find the 'dimensions' gem?

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I am using Jekyll for quite a while now to generate my blog ([source](https://github.com/MartinThoma/MartinThoma.github.io)). Today, without having changed anything in the generation process, I got

```
[...]
jekyll build --config _config_prod.yml
Configuration file: _config_prod.yml
/home/moose/GitHub/MartinThoma.github.io/_plugins/caption_tag.rb:23:in `require': cannot load such file -- dimensions (LoadError)
    from /home/moose/GitHub/MartinThoma.github.io/_plugins/caption_tag.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:74:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in require_plugin_files'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:73:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:73:in `block in require_plugin_files'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:72:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:72:in `require_plugin_files'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:18:in `conscientious_require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:79:in `setup'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:41:in `initialize'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:29:in `new'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:29:in `process'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/bin/jekyll:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
Makefile:35: recipe for target 'deploy' failed
make: *** [deploy] Error 1
```

I am not a Ruby developer, but I guess the problem is `require 'dimensions'`? However, when I execute this line in `irb` it only shows `=> true`.

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

### Diagnostic information

```
$ jekyll --version
jekyll 2.5.3
$  head -1 `which irb` 
#!/usr/bin/ruby2.1
$  head -1 `which jekyll`
#!/usr/bin/ruby2.1
```

Executing `RUBY_VERSION` in `irb` gives `=> "2.1.5"`.

Comment: Thanks. Both seem to be running the same Ruby binaries. Back to the drawing board :-/

Comment: @Casper It also generates a `Gemfile.lock`. Does that help?

Comment: @Casper Hm. Adding it to my `Gemfile` seems to fix it. However, I don't understand why this behaviour just changed. And I don't really know what the Gemfile is / does.

Comment: Ok that's good. Something must have changed for some reason, but too little info here to figure it out. But good that you have it working now.

Comment: Adding gems to Gemfile make sure bundle install all required gems and their dependencies. As simple as that! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was fixed by adding `gem 'dimensions'` to the file `Gemfile`. It now looks like this:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

# see https://github.com/paulrobertlloyd/paulrobertlloyd.com/blob/master/Gemfile
# Guard (automates development tasks)

# Jekyll (generates static files)
gem 'jekyll'
group :jekyll_plugins do
  gem 'jekyll-paginate'
  gem 'dimensions'
  gem 'rmagick'
end

# Rake (manages build tasks)
gem 'rake'
```